# Numerical recipe for computing physical bending energy of 2d metal sheet

Tags: python, graphics, computer-vision, computational-geometry, numerical-methods

Is there a way to numerically compute the bending energy of a 2d metal sheet. The 2d metal sheet lies on a regularly spaced grid so in python that would be given by a matrix of dimensions nxnx2 where n is the number of rows and columns in the grid. I would like to compute the bending energy of this 2d metal sheet in various conformations. The bending energy of a 2d metal sheet is given by [image]

I know that a closed form solution exists for the thin plate spline but how can i just implement this bending energy component numerically. A link to a paper that explains how to compute this is also acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Let us say that your function `f` is defined by a `NxM` grid of values. Then a very natural way to estimate its derivatives are [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference). The second-order partials can be approximated with the following expressions:

```
fxx[i,j] = f[i+1,j] - 2*f[i,j] + f[i-1,j]
fxy[i,j] = f[i+1,j+1] - f[i+1,j-1] - f[i-1,j+1] + f[i-1,j-1]
fyy[i,j] = f[i,j+1] - 2*f[i,j] + f[i,j-1]
```

where `i` and `j` are from `[0,N-1]` and `[0,M-1]` respectively.

Integration, on the other hand, can be realized by summation over the entire grid.

Comment: In my case the deformation grid is given by nxnx2 so that is the displacement in x and y direction of the point i,j in the nxn grid. So when I compute fxx and fyy that is a separate quantity for both the x and y displacement. So i get two values of fxx one for x displacement and one for y displacement I think. To compute the combined fxx do i simply do a square root of the sum. I dont get this part

Comment: I think that f(x,y) is a vector valued function with x and y displacements at the grid locations. I think that this is important in the computation but i dont know how